# Three-Digit Square Containing Numbers $1-9$

Tags: square-numbers

Question:

The square of $567$ is $321,489$.  These two numbers contain each of the digits from $1$ to $9$ exactly once between them.  What other three-digit number and its square have this property?

I know what the answer is, I just don't know how to get there.

Comment: I assume you're not allowed to use a computer? Also, how did you get the answer?

Comment: If you can explain how to do this with a computer I'll take it.

Comment: There's probably no better way than taking each three-digit number in turn, squaring it, and seeing which ones work. Well, you don't have to try any three-digit number with a repeated digit, or any ending in zero, one, five, or six, or any less than 316 (since the square would only be five digits), so that cuts down on the work a little.

Comment: There is some information at http://oeis.org/A059930

Comment: @Jolly I did it with `[x for x in range(317,1000) if set([int(k) for k in str(x)+str(x**2)])=={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}]`